# Docker compose can't find local package

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, grpc

So I created REST api and one grpc service in GOlang and now I want to compose it in docker compose. 
My docker-compose looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services: 
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: db_1
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: tajna
      PGDATA: /tmp
    volumes:
      - ./db/sql/user/1_create.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1-create_user.sql
      - ./db/sql/item/2_create.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/2-create_item.sql
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    networks: 
      apinetwork:
  service:
    build: ./item-service
    command: ["go", "run", "."]
    volumes:
      - .:/go/src/github.com/ajdinahmetovic/item-service
    ports:
      - "4040:4040"
    depends_on: 
      - db
    links:
      - db
    networks: 
      apinetwork:
  rest:
    image: go-rest
    build: 
      context: ./go-rest
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: ["go", "run", "main.go"]
    volumes:
      - .:/go/src/github.com/ajdinahmetovic/go-rest
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - service
    networks: 
      apinetwork:
networks:
  apinetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

After I run docker-compose up I get error that local packages that are inside of go-rest and item-service could not be found.

```
service_1  | item.go:7:2: no Go files in /go/src/github.com/ajdinahmetovic/item-service/db
service_1  | main.go:8:2: cannot find package "github.com/ajdinahmetovic/item-service/logger" in any of:
service_1  |    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/ajdinahmetovic/item-service/logger (from $GOROOT)
service_1  |    /go/src/github.com/ajdinahmetovic/item-service/logger (from $GOPATH)
service_1  | item.go:8:2: cannot find package "github.com/ajdinahmetovic/item-service/proto/v1" in any of:
service_1  |    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/ajdinahmetovic/item-service/proto/v1 (from $GOROOT)
service_1  |    /go/src/github.com/ajdinahmetovic/item-service/proto/v1 (from $GOPATH)
ajdinahmetovic_service_1 exited with code 1
rest_1     | /go/src/github.com/ajdinahmetovic/go-rest/routes/item/post.go:9:2: no Go files in /go/src/github.com/ajdinahmetovic/go-rest/db
rest_1     | /go/src/github.com/ajdinahmetovic/go-rest/routes/refreshToken.go:9:2: cannot find package "github.com/ajdinahmetovic/go-rest/httputil" in any of:
rest_1     |    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/ajdinahmetovic/go-rest/httputil (from $GOROOT)
rest_1     |    /go/src/github.com/ajdinahmetovic/go-rest/httputil (from $GOPATH)
ajdinahmetovic_rest_1 exited with code 1
```

However when I move docker compose file to go-rest folder, rest app succcessfuly runs but my item service fails. As i see problem is in my path to go apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After couple of hours I finally realized what the problem was. 
My volume path for item-service and go-rest were wrong.
Becuse my docker-compose file is on the same level with folders of projects item-service and go-rest

```
-go-rest
 -Project files
-item-service
 -Project files
-docker-compose.yaml
```

and my volume paths were

```
volumes:
      - .:/go/src/github.com/ajdinahmetovic/go-rest
volumes:
      - .:/go/src/github.com/ajdinahmetovic/item-service
```

They were not able to acces my project folder so they need to be changed to

```
volumes:
      - .:/go-rest
volumes:
      - .:/item-service
```